# A dealer sold a radio

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

A dealer sold a radio at a loss of 2.5%.Had he sold it for 100 dollars more he would have gained 7.5% For what value should he sell it in order to gain 12 1/2 % ?

My solution by my book formulae is 
Selling price = More Dollar (100+final gain)/(gain%+loss%)
=100(112.5)/7.5+2.5
=1125

Please suggest easier solutions !

Comment: This is your second question asking for an answer to a problem you know how to do. You can trust yourself from now on. Also: the way to thank someone for an answer is to accept it (the check mark) and upvote it (the up arrow) you can upvote more than one answer.

Answer (score 1):

$\$100$ is clearly $10\%$ of the original price the dealer bought the radio for (the difference between $97.5\%$ and $107.5\%$) That means he bought it for $\$1000$. To have a gain of $12.5\%$, he must sell it for $\$1125$.

Comment: Ya I can understand sir Thank you for your reply !